# Hello world script doesn't work

Tags: script

I'm trying to get a simple script "test1.sh" to work on my pi, but keep getting

```
-bash: test1: command not found
```

the script is literally:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World!"
```

and called test1.sh, located in the `/home/scripts` directory.

I can navigate to it in terminal, but it will not run.

Iv'e set the permissions to 755 on the script and the "scripts" directory

I'm trying to run from the user pi.

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you run `/bin/bash /home/scripts/test1.sh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this link helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-my-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

I was editing in windows, using notepad++ and then using winscp to move it over to the PI. I needed to save it in notepad as a unix file - oops!

Comment: That is really wierd. I use Notepad++ and Filezilla SFTP to transfer scritps over the whole time. I do a `chmod +x` and use `./filename.sh` and its fine. Possibly you are using another encoding (another language on your computer?) Make sure its UTF8 like most English PC's hsould default to.

Comment: An editor you can use on the Pi, in terminal or SSH, is `nano` - easy to use, and can have syntax highlighting enabled - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/90026/178596).

Answer (score 4):

You ***do*** call your script with a path in front, like `/home/scripts/test1.sh` or `./test1.sh`,  do you? What does `ls -la /home/scripts/test1.sh` say?

Comment: OR the script has to be in an environment path. Like /usr/src I think?

Comment: That might be a good idea: Add `$HOME/scripts` to $PATH

Comment: ls -la /home/scripts/test1.sh says: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34 Feb 24 17:27 /home/scripts/test1.sh

Comment: Why is the file owned by root? Have you tried `chown pi:pi /home/scripts/test1.sh` and then calling it again?

Comment: i did "pi:pi /home/scripts/test1.sh" and tried to run it again, and yes i run it using "/home/scripts/test1.sh", but still same error. i don't understand "$HOME/scripts to $PATH". Do i have to add this to my script?

Comment: No, you don't have to add anything to your $PATH. It would just enable you to call `test1.sh` from anywhere (without `./` or `/home/scripts`). It should've been `sudo chown pi:pi /home/scripts/test1.sh` btw.

Comment: moved it to: "/usr/src/scripts/test1.sh", did "sudo chown pi:pi /usr/src/scripts/test1.sh", then did  "/usr/src/scripts/test1.sh" but still i get error: "-bash: /usr/src/scripts/test1.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"